# How to find the number of Div added in PHP after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I have created div elements dynamically by this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var c=0;
  $(".addC").on('click', function(){
    //alert("Add More....");
    var addInput = $("<br /><input type='text' name=court_"+ c +  " id=court_"+ c +" required />");
    $(this).parent().append(addInput);
    c++;
  });

});
```

This is done for a  form that has already an input field for entering court name

```
<input type="text" name="court_name" id="court_name" required />
```

I want these values in $_POST[] php variable for further DB operations. How to find how many input fields are added and how can they be used (in php only)

Comment: Instead of a counter -> `name=court_"+ c +  "` add them as an array -> `name=court[]`. Then in php it is easy to do `count($_POST['court'])` or `foreach($_POST['court'] as $court)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use a grouping name on your forms, so that it's much easier to manage: `name="txtbox[]"`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $count = count($_POST['court_name']); // this is an array now, you can use count()
    echo $count;

    foreach($_POST['court_name'] as $court_name) {
        // your DB queries, blah blah
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <button class="addC" type="button">Add more</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="court_name[]" id="court_name" required />    
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var c = 0;
    $(".addC").on('click', function(){
        //alert("Add More....");
        var addInput = $("<br /><input type='text' name='court_name[]' id='court_"+ c +"' required />");
                                                        // ^^ use []
        $(this).parent().append(addInput);
        c++;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: @KnightRider you mean the typo? yes i have revised it

Comment: Yes a typo maybe because I have using type='text' so (min single quotes) name also should be name='court_name[]'. 1 thing more, the required attribute does not work when a text field is created using jquery but works in HTML Why?

Comment: @KnightRider what do you mean doesn't work? it works on my side, those dynamically generated textboxes still trigger when its empty, what browser are you using anyway? mines chrome 37

Comment: @KnightRider here's a [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/c2TBqd) by the way, also tried on firefox, works okay